# Can QGIS open KMZ files?

Tags: qgis, kmz, windows-xp

I know I can add KML files once I have unzipped the KMZ files, but is there a way to open KMZ files directly?

When I try to open a kmz file on QGIS 1.8.0 on Windows XP, through the all files filter, it does not accept it as a valid format.

Am I doing something wrong?

Does this all depend on OGR support?

Comment: No only KML, you need to unzip the KMZ first to retrieve the KML.

Comment: 7 Zip provides a neat dialog for right click 'open archive' and then dragging the temp.kml into a folder

Comment: On Windows in QGIS you can know open KMZ read only directly from the add layer (vector) dialog

Answer (score 20):

On a Mac, where QGIS uses the Kyngchaos.com [GDAL 1.9 Complete framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks), or on any platform where QGIS has been compiled against a GDAL build with support for [the Google LIBKML driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_libkml.html), you can open .kmz files directly using the open dialog and selecting the `All Files (*)` option, or simply drag/drop onto QGIS. (*Otherwise, you will need to decompress the .kmz to .kml files as noted by @Kurt*)

[image]

If the .kmz has multiple layers, you will be presented with a layer selection dialog (single layer .kmz files are immediately loaded):

[image]

You can select multiple layers in that dialog to import. The *Example Overlay of Multiple Datasets* .kmz file I tested ([from here](http://coastal.er.usgs.gov/flash/broward/br_small.html)) allowed multiple layer import of point, line and polygon layer types.

---

**EDIT**: You can check for ogr LIBKML driver support in your version of QGIS by running the following commands in QGIS's Python Console:

```
import osgeo.ogr
print 'Has LIBKML ogr driver: ' + str(osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName('LIBKML') is not None)
```

Comment: I believe this support comes from [gdal's ability to read ZIP archives](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/ReadInZip), which was [recently added to QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp#L267). However, I couldn't find specifics on .kmz files (needs documented somewhere).

Comment: your procedure does not work for me with qgis 1.8 under win7. does this work only under max os??

Comment: Tried it with Qgis Master b6760ce GDAL 1.9.1 on Windows XP, but no success here.

Comment: did not work for me in Qgis 1.8 in windows Vista with gdal 1.9.1

Comment: Assuming reporting Windows users are using the [OSGeo4W installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/PackageListing), it appears the gdal/ogr library that ships with it does not include [the LIBKML driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_libkml.html) (which offers reading of .kmz files). There is already [a request for including the driver in OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/291). The GDAL 1.9 Complete framework installer for Mac by [Kyngchaos.com](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) includes the LIBKML driver. (In other words, this is not an issue with QGIS, per se.)

Comment: BTW: OSGeo4W users can check their gdal/ogr available formats by opening the MSYS console and typing either `gdalinfo --formats` or `ogrinfo --formats`. On Mac, using Terminal to run the same command for ogr, it reports `"LIBKML" (read/write)`, whereas using my Windows 7 virtual machine's MSYS console, it reports no driver support. The `"KML" (read/write)` format, a different driver, is obviously supported on both platforms.

Comment: @dakcarto: i have the standalone qgis version

Comment: @Kurt I added to my answer above for checking via the Python Console for whether your QGIS version supports LIBKML.

Comment: @dakcarto: howto do this check?? thx

Answer (score 14):

as far as I know, you are right: vectors in qgis  are read and written by ogr. qgis 1.8 uses the lastest gdal/ogr, which is 1.91. you can read zipped shape-files, but *.kmz, which actually are a zip-archive containing *.kml-file(s) need to be unzipped manually before importing

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618215209/http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/import_kml.php) is a guide to create and import KML files into Quantum. It does not work for KMZ files so these would need to first be decompressed to be used in this manner.

Comment: for decompressing KMZ files just change filenameextension from KMZ to ZIP and decompress with your favorite tool (winrar, 7zip, winzip ...)

Comment: 7 Zip has a right click option on kmz's to open them up, then drag and drop the kml right outta there

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @HoRn - thanks! I have updated the link.

Answer (score 3):

You can add KML layers as any other kind of vector layer, using Layer .. Add Layer .. Add Vector Layer (or Ctrl-Shift-V).

Comment: KMZ's... not KML...

Answer (score 2):

Once you have opened the KML file in QGIS, you can also save it as a shapefile by right-clicking on the file in the layers pane and selecting 'save as'.

Comment: how about opening the KMZ first...?

Answer (score 0):

Rename `datafile.kmz` to `datafile.zip` then unzip the `*.kml` from inside.

Comment: Folks, please leave a short comment for negative votes! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have QGIS 2.18 and you can add a *.kmz file.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is simple:

1. in Google Earth, right-click on your loaded *.kmz file
2. choose "save as..." and save the file as *kml
3. Now, open the kml-file with QGIS

Tipp: if you want to save several *.kmz files and merge them in one sinlge *kml file, put your *.kmz files in Google Earth in one single folder in hte "locations" window of Google Earth. Than apply the procedure described above for the folder. One single *kml with all geogrpahic points in the folder will be produced, you can then open it with QGis.

If "on the fly projection" is activated, the points will show up on the right place in your OpenLayers Map in QGIS.

Comment: KMZs can be unzipped just as well without Google Earth.

Comment: Yes, just rename *.kmz *.zip and use the zip-tool of your choice ...

Answer (score -3):

First Open In Google Earth And Save As Kml Format File and That
you will open in QGIS 1.8....
open Vector Data File Change kml format...