# Import KML or KMZ files into Qgis

Tags: qgis, kml, kmz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can QGIS open KMZ files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32082/can-qgis-open-kmz-files)

Is it possible to import Google Earth generated KML or KMZ files into QGIS and then use these files as background data for a project?

I intend to add non-KML hydrology data to these base layers.

Can you provide some easy tutorials?

Comment: Similar: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32082/can-qgis-open-kmz-files